# Receiving 500 HTTP response when posting to website

Tags: python, http, web-scraping

I am attempting am attempting to extract some information from a website that requires a post to an ajax script.

I am trying to create an automated script however I am consitently running into an HTTP 500 error. This is in contrast to a different data pull I did from a

```
url = 'http://www.ise.com/ExchangeDataService.asmx/Get_ISE_Dividend_Volume_Data/'

paramList = ''
paramList += '"' + 'dtStartDate' + '":07/25/2014"'
paramList += ','
paramList += '"' + 'dtEndDate' + '":07/25/2014"';
paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';

response = requests.post(url, headers={
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'data': paramList,
    'dataType':'json'
    })
```

I was wondering if anyone had any recommendations as to what is happening. This isn't proprietary data as they allow you to manually download it in excel format.

Comment: Copy and paste the URL that you are trying to hit into a browser.  If it works, then there's something wrong with your code.  If it doesn't, then check your params to make sure you are sending what the server is expecting and if they are correct, contact the administrator of the site.

Comment: @Zuzlx: You can't copy and paste a POST request with data into your browser.

Comment: @abarnert  Ha!  True. If you know how to use Fiddler, the debugging process still stands.

Comment: @Zuzlx: Yeah, there are a few good plugins for doing this, and anyone doing serious client-side web development who doesn't know how to use Python with requests (or Node, etc.) from an interactive prompt like the back of his hand really, really, really should be using one as the first step as well as the first place to go for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input you're generating is not valid JSON. It looks like this:

```
{"dtStartDate":07/25/2014","dtEndDate":07/25/2014"}
```

If you look carefully, you'll notice a missing `"` before the first `07`.

This is one of many reasons you shouldn't be trying to generate JSON by string concatenation. Either build a `dict` and use `json.dump`, or if you must, use a multi-line string as a template for `str.format` or `%`.

---

Also, as bruno desthuilliers points out, you almost certainly want to be sending the JSON as the POST body, not as a `data` header in an empty `POST`. Doing it the wrong way does happen to work with some back-ends, but only by accident, and that's certainly not something you should be relying on. And if the server you're talking to isn't one of those back-ends, then you're sending the empty string as your JSON data, which is just as invalid.

---

So, why does this give you a 500 error? Probably because the backend is some messy PHP code that doesn't have an error handler for invalid JSON, so it just bails with no information on what went wrong, so the server can't do anything better than send you a generic 500 error.

Comment: the json.dump and remove of concatenation is what did it

Answer (score 1):

If that's a copy/paste from you actual code, 'data' is probably not supposed to be part of the request headers. As a side note: you don't "post to an ajax script", you post to an URL. The fact that this URL is called via an asynchronous request from some javascript on some page of the site is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like a server error. So what your posting could breaking their api due to its formatting.
Or their api could be down.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm